# Display checkbox inside a listbox

Tags: matlab, user-interface, checkbox, listbox

In my (programmatic) Matlab GUI, I have a listbox `uicontrol`.

What I want is to display checkboxes in front of each option. When a user clicks the checkbox, it's marked (and the element will be considered during the calculations later). While if the user clicks the label, a description of the selected option will be displayed in a text `uicontrol` to inform the user what the option means.

Basically, I want functionality similar to installation programs where you can select components to install and can get information about said components by clicking them (which does not necessarily mark them as selected).

Is there a way to do this with checkboxes or something similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no "ready" way for doing that - as listboxes take only plain strings as entries.

You could "manually" draw checkbox fitted into the area of the listbox, but that might mean quite a lot of work to get everything working...
Another alternative is to go for a java-componenent - e.g. using the jide components available in matlab. See e.g.

http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/using-jide-combo-boxes/

for a few examples.

Comment: Ah, that's what I feared :( I guess I'll just go with a visual workaround (buttongroup/panel+checkboxes), I don't really want to use Java... Well, thank you anyway, at least I know it's not possible now :P

Comment: You could also take a look at the undocumented `uigridcontainer` and `uiflowcontainer` - they might make the layout significantly easier to handle.

Answer (score 3):

There are actually 2 built-in controls that you could use within Matlab:

1. `com.jidesoft.swing.CheckboxList`
2. `com.mathworks.mwswing.checkboxlist.CheckBoxList`

Usage example (more details in my [Matlab-Java book](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/matlab-java-book)):

`jList = java.util.ArrayList;  % any java.util.List will be ok
jList.add(0,'First');
jList.add(1,'Second');
jList.add(2,'Third');
jList.add(3,'and last');
jCBList = com.mathworks.mwswing.checkboxlist.CheckBoxList(jList);
jScrollPane = com.mathworks.mwswing.MJScrollPane(jCBList);
[jhCBList,hContainer] = javacomponent(jScrollPane,[10,10,80,65],gcf);
set(jCBList, 'ValueChangedCallback', @myMatlabCallbackFcn);
jCBModel = jCBList.getCheckModel;
jCBModel.checkAll;
jCBModel.uncheckIndex(1);
jCBModel.uncheckIndex(3);`

[image: com.mathworks.mwswing.checkboxlict.CheckBoxList example]