# matlab app designer drop down \ list box with checkboxs

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-app-designer

Is it possible to create a drop down or list box with checkboxs ?

I'm building analysis app. 
In the first stage i get a list of subjects, and the user need the ability to choose several subjects from the list for the analysis.

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display checkbox inside a listbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21437732/display-checkbox-inside-a-listbox)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the table component to show a list. The `uitable` can take logical value on the `Data` property.
Here is a very simple example in App Designer.

```
data = { 'test1', 10, true; 'test2', 99, false };
app.UITable.Data = data;
```